# How to read a text file to a local List and return periodically to access it without using a global variable?

Tags: c#

If I declare a table like this (and populate it from a text file) how do I access the variable called data outside the block where the local variable was declared. I think I have to make the variable public but not sure how to make the table public and not sure how to access it when it is public.

```
    var data = File.ReadAllLines(path)
      .Select(line => line.Split(','))
      .Select((cols, index) => new {
    Id=index,
    HardDriveDateTime = DateTime.Parse(cols[0]),
    CurrentOpen = decimal.Parse(cols[1]),
    CurrentHigh = decimal.Parse(cols[2]),
    CurrentLow = decimal.Parse(cols[3]),
    CurrentClose = decimal.Parse(cols[4]),
    Direction = cols[5],
    Pressure  = int.Parse(cols[6])
    });
```

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If we can't easily cut & paste and reproduce your issue the question is very difficult to answer.

Comment: Dude, it is so confusing. Gotta make it to the point. Too much info

Comment: By `global variable` I think you mean `field`. Having a variable declared at class level does not break OOP. In fact, you're not able to declare a `global variable` (in the sense that they don't belong to any class) in C#.

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand

Comment: I flagged your question as 'unclear what you're asking'

Comment: If you need to persist state between calls I would declare your `List<T>` as a `private` class level variable.

Comment: Anyway, I'm going to try to answer it. However, I'm not sure at all if I correctly understood.

Comment: I deleted my answer since apparently I misunderstood your problem. However, I'm going to downvote your question as you can't downvote answers without explaining why when your question is impossible to understand.

Comment: @DavideCannizzo _I'm going to downvote your question as you can't downvote answers without explaining_, voting should be based on post content and not retaliatory. Downvotes reflect post content quality and accuracy and are not to be taken personally.

Comment: I tried to give a complete picture but I will try to boil it down.

Comment: How do I store the text file (array, static array, list? - currently a list) one time such that I can read a record (each record has 7 fields) from it whenever I deem necessary, go away perform some other logic and come back to the stored data (array, static array, list) and access it again, and again, and again until the complete stored data has been read. When I come back to read the stored data I want to read from the last "record" i read. So the stored data could be accessed 30/40/1000 times periodically.

Comment: Geeze.. ever heard of a `switch` statement?

Comment: David - I'm a former COBOL programmer so I get get your confusion.  For what you're trying to do I would look into using a database (or at least XML) instead of a text file.  Makes iterating through your data much simpler.

Comment: No, you don't do variable public (in the sense it is in Cobol). Instead you pass the variable between methods. In the case above the "data" is an anonymous  IEnumerable. Passing it wouldn't do anything useful. I have edited my message to show how you make it a known type and pass around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This is not an answer, but would be too long an messy for a comment)

In your code there is a section that starts with:

```
if(firstpass == true)
```

in that block you are reading the saved text file and getting the results into variables named "hardDriveDateTime, currentOpen...". (And if I got your code right, you want to do that for last line?)

As an old Cobol programmer, probably you would instead look at those lines as a table where those variables are column names maybe. Then that block could be rewritten as:

```
var data = File.ReadAllLines(path)
  .Select(line => line.Split(','))
  .Select((cols, index) => new {
    Id=index,
    HardDriveDateTime = DateTime.Parse(cols[0]),
    CurrentOpen = decimal.Parse(cols[1]),
    CurrentHigh = decimal.Parse(cols[2]),
    CurrentLow = decimal.Parse(cols[3]),
    CurrentClose = decimal.Parse(cols[4]),
    Direction = cols[5],
    Pressure  = int.Parse(cols[6])
});
```

For your sample data given above this looks like:

```
Id|HardDriveDateTime   |CurrentOpen|CurrentHigh|CurrentLow|CurrentClose|Direction|Pressure
0 |7/20/2018 2:55:57 PM| 2804.5    | 2804.5    | 2804.5   | 2804.5     |   B     |  2210
1 |7/20/2018 3:07:57 PM| 2804.75   | 2804.75   | 2804.75  | 2804.75    |   S     |  125
2 |7/20/2018 3:11:06 PM| 2803.5    | 2803.5    | 2803.5   | 2803.5     |   B     |  255
3 |7/20/2018 3:14:42 PM| 2804      | 2804      | 2804     | 2804       |   S     |  -202
4 |7/20/2018 3:17:50 PM| 2802.75   | 2802.75   | 2802.75  | 2802.75    |   B     |  411
5 |7/20/2018 3:20:15 PM| 2803.75   | 2803.75   | 2803.75  | 2803.75    |   S     |  -1126
```

IMHO dealing with a table (an IEnumerable) like this is much easier.

HTH

EDIT: Variables are scoped to their enclosing {}. To overcome this, it is tempting to create global variables (as you did), however they really make things worse. Instead, you can pass those variables where they needed. For example in this case there could be a ReadTheFile("with a given path") method, and it returns back that table as a typed IEnumerable. In the code I gave, that IEnumerable's rows were anonymous, and only good locally inside the surrounding {}. Instead we could create a class that matches that table's structure and could pass it around. You had XYValues class in your code. Like that one we create another (in a separate file, then 
dealing with it is easier in a large project).

```
// MyData.cs
namespace yourNameSpaceName
{
    public class MyData
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime HardDriveDateTime { get; set; }
        public decimal CurrentOpen { get; set; }
        public decimal CurrentHigh { get; set; }
        public decimal CurrentLow { get; set; }
        public decimal CurrentClose { get; set; }
        public string Direction { get; set; }
        public int Pressure { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then our original "var data = ..." code becomes (also lets assume we have separated this into another method of its own):

```
public IEnumerable<MyData> ReadTheData(string path)
{

var data = File.ReadAllLines(path)
  .Select(line => line.Split(','))
  .Select((cols, index) => new MyData {
    Id=index,
    HardDriveDateTime = DateTime.Parse(cols[0]),
    CurrentOpen = decimal.Parse(cols[1]),
    CurrentHigh = decimal.Parse(cols[2]),
    CurrentLow = decimal.Parse(cols[3]),
    CurrentClose = decimal.Parse(cols[4]),
    Direction = cols[5],
    Pressure  = int.Parse(cols[6])
});

return data;

}
```

Here, we added "MyData" right after the new keyword and before the { inside second select. That makes our IEnumerable typed as MyData. We could write:

```
IEnumerable<MyData> data = ...
```

instead of:

```
var data = ...
```

Those are the same thing and we let the compiler infer that for us (in Visual Studio, if you hover your mouse on to "data" or var, it would show you the type it infers as a tooltip).

Now that this is another separate method and typed we could use this method elsewhere like this:

```
//...
   var theData = ReadTheData(@"c:\MyFolder\MyLogFile.txt");

// do something with the returned IEnumerable<MyData>
// for example chart this data using Data.Visualization.dll

    var series = new Series("Default");
    var area = new ChartArea("Default");
    var legend = new Legend("Default");

    var chart = new Chart();
    chart.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    chart.Series.Add(series);
    chart.ChartAreas.Add(area);
    series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;

    series.Points.DataBind(data, "Id", "Pressure", null);

    var form = new Form { Height = 800, Width = 1000 };
    form.Controls.Add(chart);
    form.Show();
}
```

Or you could simply iterate, or go to first, last or query this IEnumerable as you see fit.

Comment: OK Thanks for your responses. Cetin.....I tried producing the table as you suggested. Immediately after I put this....var stuff = data;
    
    foreach (var s in stuff)
    {
     Print(s);
    } and received this......{ Id = 0, HardDriveDateTime = 7/20/2018 2:55:57 PM, CurrentOpen = 2804.5, CurrentHigh = 2804.5, CurrentLow = 2804.5, CurrentClose = 2804.5, Direction = B, Pressure = 2210 }
{ Id = 1, HardDriveDateTime = 7/20/2018 3:07:57 PM, CurrentOpen = 2804.75, CurrentHigh = 2804.75, CurrentLow = 2804.75, CurrentClose = 2804.75, Direction = S, Pressure = 125 }

Comment: But once I go outside these brackets...the program does not know what "data" means and responds with this error when I compile...."The name 'data' does not exist in the current context." So my question is how do I access the table (ienumerable) outside the brackets/braces it was declared in?

Comment: So that is the general problem I am having. It does not matter if i use array, List or a table....once I go outside of the immediate { braces } where these things are declared and populated, the program doesn't recognize them anymore. How am I supposed to query the table I created and get output?

Comment: @DavidDuggan, OK replying to that in a comment is hard, so I will edit the reply itself and add there.

Comment: @DavidDuggan, I edited the message. If you need sampling on iteration and\or querying let me know.

Comment: Thank You very much Cetin for your detailed response. I started coding the first block in your edit but i didn't know what to do after that. Let me digest what you have posted and code it into my project and then I will know where I stand. I did not understand variable scoping before although I have had quite a few related compile errors. Now that I am aware of it I will pay better attention.Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Cetin, I had one last question for you - I edited the question above. @CetinBasoz

Comment: @DavidDuggan, I actually answered that one in the edited part of my answer. If you really need it to exist for a broader scope (say for the whole life of your application) then you could declare the IEnumerable<MyData> on top level (making it global). That is not something suggested to do, but is not too much scary either, especially the amount of data that resides in memory is not too big. If you think you need more instant replies then you can reach me on my Skype (id: cbasoz@passport.com). I don't mean to be rude to the rest of SO community, I understand you as an another old DB developer.